# Is it possible to just download the whole sharepoint enviromment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup

is it possible to download the whole Sharepoint Strukture of sharepoint web to an localhost and view it on localhost.

We want to backup our sharepoint Server to a NAS and if we need it being able to view the last backups.

If yes how would this be possible over Unix?

thanks,
Raavgo

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to just download the whole SharePoint environment?**

- `SharePoint Online:` No, It's not possible!
- `SharePoint Server:` You can do that by performing backup and restore.

**Is it possible to view it on localhost?**

- `SharePoint Online:` No, It's not possible!
- `SharePoint Server:` You must have SharePoint environment with the same version and the same CU or higher to can restore the taken backup. check [Migrate web application to another farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

**Can we take a back up our SharePoint sites?**

- `SharePoint Online:` Backup and restore operations are not allowed in SharePoint online, to can take a backup you should open [an Office 365 support ticket](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Contact-Office-365-for-business-support-Admin-Help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b) or Using a 3rd party tool.
- `SharePoint Server:` Backup and restore operations are allowed for farm, web application, site.

**Check also**

- [Migrate web application to another farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [The 4 Options You Need to Know About SharePoint Online Backup and Restore](https://threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to download a SharePoint online site.
Maybe with a web catcher software... but you'll certainly not be able to use it as it shown to you online.

So... for me it's not possible.