# Hosting a SharePoint site on the internet

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, public-website

I have read the other threads regarding this, but all those are like self-hosted on their own domain sites and others. I created a personal site on the office 365 sharepoint, I have a website hosting plan like a service similar to GoDaddy. I read that I can't export the files from sharepoint for that hosting,

Is there a way that I can take the personal site out of sharepoint or just host it somehow from my hosting plan?

Answer (score 1):

**Can I take the personal site out of sharepoint or just host it somehow from my hosting plan?**

**No**, you can't move and host your **SharePoint Online site** at any other hosting plan providers!

Check also [Is it possible to just download the whole sharepoint enviromment?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248865/is-it-possible-to-just-download-the-whole-sharepoint-enviromment/248896#248896)